# Determining Whether an Array is a Palindrome in Assembly

Tags: arrays, assembly, mips32, spim

I am trying to check whether an array is a palindrome or not. So first I take the size of array in $s0 then I loop to fill the array with user input.

SPIM gives a "memory out of bounds" message and I can't figure out why. Any ideas? :")

```
.data
array: .space 80 # max 20 inputs
palMsg: .asciiz "This array is a palindrome!"
notPalMsg: .asciiz "This array is not a palindrome!"

.text

.globl main
main:

  # take number of elements in array and save value in $s0
  li $v0, 5
  syscall
  add $s0, $v0, $zero

  # initialize a counter $t0 and an offset $t1
  li $t0, 0
  li $t1, 0

  # initialize array with user's inputs
  loop:
  li $v0, 5
  syscall
  addi $t0, $t0, 1
  sw $v0, array($t1)
  addi $t1, $t1, 4
  bne $t0, $s0, loop

  # check if palindrome or not [$t0 goes from left to right and $t1 does the opposite]
  li $t0, 0
  mul $t1, $s0, 4
  addi $t1, $t1, -4
  test:
    lw $t5, array($t0)
    lw $t6, array($t1)
    bne $t5, $t6, notPal
    addi $t0, $t0, 4
    addi $t1, $t1, -4
    blt $t0, $t1, test
  lw $a0, palMsg
  j exit

  notPal:
    lw $a0, notPalMsg
    j exit

  # print msg then terminate
  exit:
    li $v0, 4
    syscall
    li $v0, 10
    syscall

.end
```

Comment: "memory out of bounds" usually means that some instruction is trying to read value from invalid memory address. Use SPIM built-in debugger to find that instruction, and check how it got the invalid address (may take some effort to track down the true origin of the problem).

Comment: Actually this caught my eye a bit more, as the code is quite decent (only few problems/inefficiencies) and I didn't spot the bug on the first read (had to try in MARS debugger myself). Turns out it's simple typo `lw $a0, palMsg` will load the four letters from string into `a0` (lw = load word), not the address of message. Should be `la $a0, palMsg` to load the address (la = load address). (same for the `notPalMsg`).  .. another bug in code - you don't test if inputted size is > 0. (technically size < 2 is always sort of palindrome, even without reading input values).

Comment: And another comment about the code... `mul $t1, $s0, 4` - this will drive any old time programmer furious. `4` is power of two, so to multiply by `4` you need only to shift the bits by two positions to left, i.e. `sll $t1, $s0, 2` ... it's like on paper if somebody would give you "37 * 100" and you would start to calculate it instead of just appending two zeroes to the "37". For computer multiplying by power of two is same as for humans multiplying by powers of 10 in decimal base. Shift left by 2 just "appends two zero bits" to the value.

Comment: My bad! I dunno how I made such a silly mistake! 

@Ped7g, you rock! Thanks a lot for the tips!